# Вставить символ в слово между символами

Tags: c, c++

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть исходный массив, в который пользователь будет вводить текcт, есть массив под букву, которую нужно вставить в слово, и есть результирующий массив, в котором будет слово и вставленная буква в слове.

Как мне говорил учитель, что Word можно объявить как переменную, а не массив, но когда пользователь вводить букву, приложение просто крашится с окном ошибки (стоит windows xp).

Самая основная проблема, что при пересадке пропадает первая буква исходного текста! На самом деле важно то, что после того, как пользователь выбрал букву, у нас пропадает первая буква в исходном тексте, сам проверял.

Мне главное понять, почему буква пропала. Заранее спасибо за ответы и внимание!

Внизу есть закомментированые циклы, т.е. ввод букв до позиции и после.

---

Не обращайте внимание на копирование в цикле с 1, это я проверял, правда ли символ пропадает, я знаю, что с 0 надо вводить.
Задачу я сам решил, всем спасибо!

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(){
  char text[10]; //наш исходный массив, предполагаемый текст - helloworld
  char word[1]; //(можно ли объявлять его не как массив?) наша буква
  char test[11]; //наш результирующий массив

  int position = 0, i; //позиция и счетчик

  printf("Enter text: ");
  gets(text); //вводим текст
  printf("%s", text); //проверяем, правильно ли введен (+правильно)

  printf("\nEnter word: ");
  fgets(word, 2, stdin); //вводим букву
  printf("%c", word[0]); //проверяем букву

  cout << "\nEnter position: ";
  cin >> position;
  cout << "\nPosition: " << position;

  position --; //мы считаем позицию с 0, пользователь с 1

  for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){ //перенос букв из исходного массива в результирующий, переносит правильно, а первая буква пропадает
    test[i] = text[i];
    printf("%c", test[i]); //отлавливаем, попадают ли буквы в результирующий массив
    getch();
    //if(i == position) не работает //попытка вставить заданную букву на позицию результирующего массива, а после неё продолжить вставлять буквы из исходного массива
      //test[i] = 0;
  }

  /*for(i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    printf("%c", test[i]);
    getch();
  }*/

    /*for(i = 0; i > position; i++){
      test[i] = text[i];
      printf("%c", test[i]);
      getch();  
    }*/

  getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, не используйте `gets`, никогда. Представьте себе, что пользователь ввёл 100 символов — как вы думаете, что произойдёт? (Это важный вопрос, убедитесь, что вы в точности понимаете это.) И да, если функция доступна, это [не значит](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7423691/276994), что использовать её хорошая идея.

Во-вторых, массивы в C (ну и в C++) нумеруются начиная с нуля. Поэтому ваш цикл копирования неверен.

В-третьих, да, под один символ вполне можно выделить переменную типа `char`. При этом вводить её при помощи `fgets` (да и `gets`) будет неправильно, т. к. эти функции дописывают в хвост строки `\0`. Ваш код сейчас тоже неверен, т. к. он выделяет лишь один символ, и тем самым не учитывает финальный `\0` (это отвлекаясь от того факта, что пользователь программы может ввести сколько угодно символов, как раньше).

Исправьте это и смотрите дальше.

---

Ещё одно замечание: вы пишете на дикой смеси C и C++. В C++ массивы символов практически не используются в качестве строк, вместо них используется `std::string`. Сейчас это наверняка неважно, но станет важно позже. Если вам говорят, что C — подмножество C++, и код на C является правильным кодом на C++, можете сразу отмечать внутри, что этот человек плохо понимает и C, и C++. C — не подмножество C++, а его родовая травма: ради [чисто маркетинговой](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/practical-language.html) идеи совместимости с C в C++ на уровне синтаксиса многие вещи в C++ реализованы ужасно.

---

Кстати, для операций со строками в C есть довольно много встроенных функций наподобие `strcpy` и `strcat`. Но лучше сначала поработать со строками вручную, эти функции делают именно то, что и вы делаете.

Comment: Кстати, чисто академический интерес: код на С не является кодом на С++, например, потому, что С не требует инклудить headers, если пользуешься некоторыми базовыми функциями (а ля printf), а C++ требует. Соответственно, что компилится на C, не обязательно соберется на С++. Но есть ли другие различия?

Comment: Я так и не понял, почему у меня пропадает первый символ.

На самом деле, мне попался горе учитель...

Всё таки и не понял, через какую функцию будет логично вводить один символ?

Раз в C++ многие вещи реализованы ужасно, тогда на каком языке писать С или С++?

Comment: @smallFish: есть небольшие различия. Например, конверсия указателей: [C](http://ideone.com/LUcUCR), [C++](http://ideone.com/GbItU5).

А ещё, в C99 есть `restrict`, а в C++ нет.

Comment: @DrummerIF: Для начала, возьмите и прочитайте книжку по C++ (поищите гуглом по сайту, вопросы о книгах задавались неоднократно). По поводу пропажи символа, вы исправили цикл копирования? Сделайте его от 0.

По поводу ввода, может пригодиться `fgets` (но не `gets`) и `scanf`. А также `getline`, если ваша платформа поддерживает его.

Мне кажется, стоит знать оба языка, C и C++, и понимать их «идеологию». Вопрос о том, какие языки стоит учить, большой и сложный (и вроде бы обсужался тут тоже).